# What does it mean, when packaged meat depressurizes itself?

Tags: food-safety, meat, raw-meat, packaging

If I keep meat for a few days after it's use-by date, the packaging starts to look sucked-in, as if the amount of air has been reduced. Since it is a sealed package, I can't think how that could be. What causes this de-pressurization, and does it mean the meat is no longer safe to eat?

Comment: Where is it stored?  Is it in the freezer?

Comment: I tend to be more worried when the package starts bulging.  (that's a sign of microbial activity).  I've never seen the sucked in look.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Stored in the fridge.

Comment: @Joe I have seen it bulging, but very rarely - the sucked in look is much more common for me. Might be a difference in how it is prepared before packaging.

Comment: I've seen the sucked in ones, and as far as I know, it is also a sign of bacterial activity. Something is converting the gas in your package into something else, with a different density, and I can't imagine what that something can be than a bacterial colony. I'm not writing an answer until I have seen it confirmed by some source, but I don't think it can be anything else. Besides that, the answer to "is it safe" is "no" because it's past it use-by date, no matter whether you can perceive any change in the meat.